# jQuery form input select by id

Tags: jquery

### Code

```
<form id='a'>
  <input id='b' value='dave'>
</form>
```

### Question

How do I get the value from input 'b' while at the same time make sure it is inside 'a' (something like `$('#a:input[id=b]')`).

I only ask because I might have other inputs called 'b' somewhere else in my page and I want to make sure I'm getting the value from the correct form.

Comment: All elements on the DOM really should have unique ids regardless of the parent container.  It pays dividends in the future.

Comment: Yeah but I'm using django and it name my fields automatically and I have a number of 'b' fields in different models on the same page. What's a coder supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know much about Django but if the framework encourages DOM elements with the same id on a single page then it is flawed.  I say this with great personal risk to my reputation because Django and Python developers are some of the most rabidly loyal :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do that using the descendant selectors:

```
 $("#a #b")
```

However, id values are supposed to be unique on a page.

Comment: @Sevenearths - it may work, but you would do well to heed the advice of everyone here who has said that IDs should be unique. Use a class instead; it's zero extra effort, it will make your code valid, and it may just save you time in the future.

Comment: (see above) All my fields ids are named automatically. I can't use the class attribute of the form as this is being used for css and consistency. Because of the automation of the form elements I'd have to re-do my db and give everything awkward names. Is it really worth it?

Comment: @Sevenearths - you can use the class attribute even if you're already using it, because it's perfectly legal to have multiple classes in a single item.

Comment: @Sevenearths This behaviour is configurable in django. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-configuring-label for details.

Comment: I have acquiesced. all my inputs are now uniquely named with `auto_id` (Thanks for the link Vince)

Answer (score 16):

For example like this:

```
var value = $("#a").find("#b").val()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just target the id directly:

```
var value = $('#b').val();
```

If you have more than one element with that id in the same page, it won't work properly anyway. You have to make sure that the id is unique.

If you actually are using the code for different pages, and only want to find the element on those pages where the id:s are nested, you can just use the descendant operator, i.e. space:

```
var value = $('#a #b').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one element with the same ID, then you have invalid HTML.

But you can acheive the same result using classes instead. That's what they're designed for.

```
<input class='b' ... >
```

You can give it an ID as well if you need to, but it should be unique.

Once you've got the class in there, you can reference it with a dot instead of the hash, like so:

```
var value = $('#a .b').val();
```

or

```
var value = $('#a input.b').val();
```

which will limit it to 'b' class elements that are inputs within the form (which seems to be close to what you're asking for).

Comment: nice to see my coding standard are so low that they break things. (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
$('#b').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).val(); 
})
```

Or if you don't click it (and I guess you won't) and you will use submit button, you can use `prev()` function either.